# Efeito em abertura de janela WPF

Tags: wpf

gostaria de criar um efeito na abertura da minha janela em WPF, semelhante à abertura das janelas de Clima e Mail do Windows 10.

Quando eu abrir a janela, o Background fica com uma cor e uma imagem, depois isso tudo desaparece, e a janela é exibida Normalmente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe de algum tutorial, dica ou página que explique como usar este recurso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, a animação que você deseja pode ser criada a partir da seguinte estrutura:

```
<Grid x:Name="Background">
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="item1" From="item2" To="item3" DecelerationRatio="0.9" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
```

**Explicando Melhor**

Dentro do seu controle (no caso o grid), você adiciona o container *Triggers* (gatilho) que vai acionar o seu evento, logo em seguida defina *EventTrigger* como container do evento e *BeginStoryBoard* para expicificar o que acontece no inicio do evento e *RoutedEvent* recebe o nome do controle alvo da animação e seu gatilho, a estrutura pode mudar dependendo da animação que desejar.

item1 é a propriedade alvo, onde será aplicada a animação.

item2 o valor inicial desta propriedade.

item3 o valor final desta propriedade.

Duration é o tempo de duração da animação, no exemplo acima está em 1/2 de segundo.

para mais detalhes:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364529/Animation-using-Storyboards-in-WPF
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms742868(v=vs.110).aspx

fonte:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms742868(v=vs.110).aspx